# Adding a cryptocurency ticker to website

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I'm trying to understand to implement API's from a third-party to my website. Right now I'm looking at the documentation from https://docs.bitfinex.com/v1/reference#rest-public-ticker . I find it hard to understand how I can implement a single ticker (for example BTC/USD) with Javascript. Can you guys give me some cues where to look at or how to understand API's like these. Thank you.

Comment: That API won't work with in-browser JavaScript. It's meant to be used with node.js, i.e. server-side JavaScript. You need an API that accepts CORS requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API doesn't allow CORS, so you won't be able to use Javascript in the client's browser to do this.

If it were allowed, you could just do something like this with jQuery:

```
$.get('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd').done(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

So, you can create a file on your server (say, in PHP), and write the to make the very simple HTTP request above. You can google "GET request with PHP". Return that in the server response, and then in the code above (which goes in the client) you can query your file (you will change the `https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd` above to be the file on your server, like `https://example.com/load-bitfinex.php`.

This is called a proxy, and it can bypass the CORS restriction (because the file is hosted on your own domain).

Optionally you can do this with server-side rendering only and just simply query the endpoint using backend code and then render it.

It's worth noting in your example that it's using 2 separate code blocks for a single example (it shows both a plain old GET request as well as using their library). Both methods are not required, only a simple get request to this URL (you can click it now to see a preview):

https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd